# f"{tesseract_cmd} is not installed or it's not in your PATH."

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

So I've followed a tutorial about using tesseract using a python, and I've installed the tesseract from https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki

And using :

`pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"`

In the python file, but still get a result like this:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\testBase.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pytesseract
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .pytesseract import ALTONotSupported
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 89
    f"{tesseract_cmd} is not installed or it's not in your PATH."
                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And I've searching how to fix it, like adding the tesseract.exe to the PATH but still didnt work. I can't even use the tesseract command on the cmd

Is there a step that I'm missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fix the error by update python version from 2.7 into 3.9